# Empty list returned from saving function

Tags: python

This what I asked to do:

> `save_friends(filename, friends_list)` takes a file name and a friends list and writes that list to thefile in the correct format. So, for example,
>   save_friends('friends.csv', load_friends('friends.csv'))
>   should overwrite the friends le with exactly the same content.

This is my code:

```
def save_friends(filename, friends_list): 
    """
    take a file name and a friends list and wrients that list
    to the file in the correct format

    save_friend(file, list) -> list
    """
    friends_list = []
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    for friend in friends_list:
        f.write(friend+ '\n')
    return friends_list 
    f.close()
```

The problem is when I run the text code(a code provided by school that dose some simple tests), it tells me

```
>>>save_friends('friends_output.csv', d)
[ ]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\study\Yr 1\Semister1\CSSE1001\Assignment\sample_tests.py", line 84, in <module>
    assert res == None, "save_friends didn't return None"
AssertionError: save_friends didn't return None
```

So, how can I return 'None' while the input is not really a list(Like the input 'd' in this circumstance)?

Comment: I think you're basic problem is that you don't know what exactly your function should do. I don't think you should return anything in this case, because the list doesn't change.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code you posted here, the code *as copied here* won't run. There is a space missing on the `for` loop line. Presumably your actual code doesn't have that error, otherwise you would not even have gotten to the `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 2):

You replace the `friends_list` argument with an empty list at the top of your function:

```
friends_list = []
```

Remove that line.

Also, your function should not return anything; you need to remove the `return` line too to pass the assignment test, which expected `None` from the function (which is the default).

Note that by returning early, you never call `.close()` on the file either.

Comment: Should also remove the `return friends_list` line, no?

Comment: I don't get what he wants to do. On the one hand, he wants to return a list, on the other hand None.

Comment: @camelNeck: The function's specification doesn't say anything about returning a list- I'm pretty sure that was a mistake from the start

Comment: @camelNeck: The homework instructions do not say he needs to return a list, only his docstring does. The assignment test traceback shows he is wrong about returning a list.